# Conflict in package installed with both package and el-get?

Tags: package, install

I list my packages:

```
;; List all packages installed with el-get-install (look for "installed" to find installed packages)
(el-get-list-packages)

;; List packages installed with "package-install"
(package-list-packages)
```

And I see that the package `projectile` (which is not working fine) is installed both with `el-get` and `package-install`.

- Does this mean the package is duplicated?
- Which installation takes precedence?
- How do I uninstall packages installed with `el-get-install`?
- How do I uninstall packages installed with `package-install`?
- Is it possible to globally disable all packages installed with `package-install`?
- Is it possible to globally disable all packages installed with `el-get-install`?

Answer (score 2):

> - Does this mean the package is duplicated?

Probably.  Though it's also possible to tell el-get to install packages via package.el.  Use `M-x el-get-describe` to see the `:type` of the package, if it's `elpa` then that means el-get is listing the package.el installation, otherwise it's duplicated.

> - Which installation takes precedence?

Depends on the order you call `el-get` and `package-initialize` in your init file.  Use `M-x locate-library` to find out where a lisp file is loaded from.

> - How do I uninstall packages installed with el-get-install?
> - How do I uninstall packages installed with package-install?

`M-x el-get-remove` and `M-x package-delete` respectively.

> - Is it possible to globally disable all packages installed with package-install?
> - Is it possible to globally disable all packages installed with el-get-install?

To prevent loading el-get packages during startup, remove the call to `el-get` from your init file.  For package.el packages, remove the call to `package-initialize` and also set `package-enable-at-startup` to `nil`.

There's no easy way to disable packages after the fact in a running Emacs session (you can try `unload-feature`, if you know the relevant "features", but it's not guaranteed to completely undo all the effects of loading, depending on what the package did).

Comment: Wow, great, thanks for the effort. I was not expecting such a detailed answer, addressing all my points.